# How to convert a number multiplied by a symbol to integer in sympy?

Tags: python, math, sympy

for example:

```
((360/2)*x)/2 # output : 90.0*x
# I want the output to be : 90*x
int(((360/2)*x)/2) # TypeError
```

Is there any function that I can use to convert 90.0*x to 90*x

Comment: use int division (e.g `//`)

Comment: You can also use nsimplify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @OscarBenjamin

```
nsimplify(((360/2)*x)/2) # output : 90*n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xreplace` to go through your expression and make the changes:

```py
>>> eq
2.0*x
>>> eq.xreplace({i: int(i) for i in eq.atoms(Float) if i == int(i)})
2*x
```